# dual syntax highlighting in ACE

Tags: javascript, python, ace-editor

I'd like to enable syntax highlighting of JS within a python script using the ACE editor.  Specifically, I'd like something like this:

```
#python stuff...
foo_dict = {}

foo = """<script> var foo = 3 </script>"""
```

where everything in the script tag is formatted for JS, and the rest is formatted for python.

I am stuck at square one, and before manually munging a new "mode" together I'm hoping you all have a neat answer.  Thanks in advance.