# Ace editor / embed multiple syntax highlight

Tags: syntax, editor, ace-editor

I'm using ace editor with "html" mode for web programming as a web IDE. I can highlight code for HTMl, CSS and JavaScript. It works nicely. This is my code:

```
    editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/html');
```

I'd like to embed coffeescript and typescript syntax highlight too when using the

```
    <script type='text/coffeescript'>
```

and

```
    <script type='text/typescript'>
```

tags on the page. Ace does have modes for these languages but they are separate files (mode-coffee.js and mode-typescript.js) and I don't know how I could embed these into mode-html.js. The code is rather complicated.

Could you kindly help me out? I've been studying these files for several hours now and I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Does this address your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278238/ace-code-editor-set-language-dynamically

Comment: @DerekBrown No, it doesn't help, I've already seen that topic, it just says how I can set the mode but I know that and it works for me. What I need is merge multiple modes like add the "coffeescript" syntax highlight to the "html" mode and I don't know how. Thanks.

Comment: I see what you are saying- your edit clarifies the question a lot.

Comment: This too has already been asked, but without an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199849/dual-syntax-highlighting-in-ace

Comment: I have done pretty extensive searching, and I can't find anything to suggest that this feature is supported in `ace-editor`.  I would open a new issue on their GitHub page and request the feature. https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace

Comment: @DerekBrown Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible.  We are looking into adding this as a feature, which is  being tracked by a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3435).

Answer (score 0):

```
    
<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-modelist.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


<script>
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
editor.session.setMode('ace/mode/html');
// editor.session.setMode('ace/mode/php');
editor.setHighlightActiveLine(false);


// autocomplete
editor.setOptions({
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    
});

// add Custom snippet
var staticWordCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        var wordList = ["<?php ?>", , `<div class=""> </div>`];
        callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
            return {
                caption: word,
                value: word,
                meta: "static"

            };
        }));
        // set mode php
        var modelist = ace.require("ace/ext/modelist")
        var filePath = ".php"
        var mode = modelist.getModeForPath(filePath).mode
        console.log(mode);
        editor.session.setMode(mode)

    }
}
langTools.addCompleter(staticWordCompleter);
```

Comment: <script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-modelist.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> i did missed

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**